# building list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list

I want to define a list of vectors. The vector length is 4 and the length of list is N.

I am trying

```
list A=as.list(rep(c("","","",""),length=N)
```

but I am getting output

```
[[1]]
[1] ""

[[2]]
[1] ""

[[3]]
[1] ""
```

But I need the output as

```
[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" ""

[[2]]
[1] "" "" "" ""

[[3]]
[1] "" "" "" ""
```

How could this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
N<-10
lapply(1:N,function(x)rep(c("","","",""),N))
```

actually if you're not repeating N times (i.e. all items the same), you probably need:

```
lapply(1:N,function(x)c("","","",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Troy's, but different enough that I think it's worth posting:

```
 replicate(N, character(4), s=F)
```

With `N==3`:

```
[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" ""

[[2]]
[1] "" "" "" ""

[[3]]
[1] "" "" "" ""
```